# Get ComponentRef from DOM element

Tags: angular, interact.js

It has already been answered how to get the DOM element from an Angular 2 component: `ComponentRef.location.nativeElement` (ComponentRef.location gives the ElementRef that gives a direct access to DOM).

But **how to do the opposite, i.e. get the reference to the ComponentRef when I only have the native DOM object?**

I am in the case when I try to drag/drop Angular 2 components using interact.js. The library uses callback functions to notify which element is dragged, and on which element we are trying to drop. An `event` object is provided, and the only useful information I found was the DOM element (`target` attribute).

**Example:**

```
interact('my-component-tag').draggable({
    // ...
    onstart: function (event:any) {
        var dom = event.target; // ref to the <my-component-tag> tag
        // How to find the Angular ComponentRef object here?
    }
    // ...
}).dropzone({
    // ...
    ondragenter: function (event:any) {
        var targetDom = event.relatedTarget; // targeted <my-component-tag> tag
        // Same question here,
        // to identify where we want to insert the dragged element.
    }
    // ...
});
```

**[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ilmlYrDokVsoJBrHJNOK?p=preview)**

You can check the handlers in `src/Interactjs.ts`. Open the console to see associated logs and drop a component on another. I have information about elements by the DOM, but I want Angular components instead, let's say access the `count` attribute.

**Findings and tries:**

I found a [solution for the jquery-ui-draggable plugin](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0), but this trick does not work here, at least for the target where to drop.

There are also [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975265/angular2-dom-query-to-elementref) about how to insert in the DOM, talking about the DomAdapter, but I haven't found any method that seems to help from DOM to Angular component reference.

I just thought about a manual search over my components: looping in the DOM nodes, count to find the position, and reach the component from the component list at the same position, but it is so ugly...

Any advice on that is welcome. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be achieved using the [ElementProbe API](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1992). It is mainly intended for debugging / protractor integration, similar to `element.scope()` in Angular 1.

In order to use this API, you would need to include `ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS` in your `bootstrap()` call. You will then be able to get any component instance by calling the global `ng.probe()`.

For example, here is how you get the component instance for the current event target:

```
ng.probe(event.target).componentInstance
```

**[Updated Plunker showing this is action](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5aOltFBODal6BAvNEre?p=preview)**

You can see the actual implementation of the ElementProbe API [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fb16c394965e210b0e1a656da3e2b261bc75c544/modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/debug/debug_element_view_listener.ts).

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was not possible, thanks! The advices I got from angular gitter group was to change the design to make it more the Angular way. I actually already migrated to a completely different code structure to avoid manipulating the DOM, but your solution clearly solves the issue as presented in my question.

Comment: Does this still exist under 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this. I was able to accomplish it by using a combination of @ViewChildren in the "parent" component class and setting a unique identifier on the "child" component itself.

So, it the parent component, you have:

```
@ViewChildren(YourChildComponent)
elements: QueryList<YourChildComponent>;
```

Then, in your child component, you do the following (note that I imported the angular2 uuid package, but you can use any mechanism for generating a unique id):

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {    
    this.UniqueID = UUID.UUID();
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('unique-id', this.UniqueID);
}

 //and we define a public property here
UniqueID: string;
```

Now, you can access your children and match them up by identifier like this:

```
private findElementByNativeDOMObject(el: any) : YourChildComponent{


let uniqueId = el.attributes.getNamedItem('unique-id').value;
if ( ! uniqueId)
  return null;

// ok, let's go through our children
return this.elements.find( x=> x.UniqueID == uniqueId);
```

}